# How to use @RefreshScrop in spring-integration project configured as xml config

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration to ftp files to a remote server and I am using xml based config.  I would like to use spring cloud config  , so I can move all the properties files to git and use @RefreshScope to refresh the properties.  What's the best way to achieve this in spring integration which has only xmls.

I have the below code :

```
<bean id="inDefaultSftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />
        <property name="user"
            value="${sftp.username}" />
        <property name="password"
            value="${sftp.password}" />
        <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `scope="refresh"` and `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` for that bean definition.
Something like this:

```
<bean id="inDefaultSftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory"
    scope="refresh">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sftp.password}" />
    <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response.  I will definitely try that, but I was asking in general for all SI components.  We don't have the scope option for SI components  <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
  filename-pattern="sa*.txt"
  auto-startup="true" channel="inboundReceiveChannel"
  session-factory="inSftpSessionFactory"
  local-directory="file:${sftp.ofsll.sharedFolder}"
  remote-directory="${sftp.remoteDirectory}"
  auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true">
  <int:poller cron="${cronjob.expr}"
   max-messages-per-poll="10" />
 </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: That’s true. It’s not going to work there because such a custom tag provides several beans. And also there is a deep dependency on the channel to interact with. So, these beans can only be as singletons. On the hand I think `@RefreshScope` only makes for custom end-user beans

Comment: Thank You!  I believe @RefreshScope will not work, even if I change from xml based config to Java config or Annotation based right ?  Just want to confirm, before I go that route.

Comment: That’s it’s not. You may consider to use dynamic integration flows to rebuild in case of refresh event: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows